# Thymleaf Spring MVC Button executes Java method

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

So this is what I have in my HTML file:

```
<ul>
    <th:block th:object="${Post}">
        <li class="post" th:each="Post : ${Posts}">
            <p  th:text ="${Post.getPostText()}"></p>
            <button th:onclick = "${Post.upvote()}">Upvote</button>
            <button th:onclick = "${Post.downvote()}">Downvote</button>
            <p th:text = "${Post.getPostVotes()}"></p>
        </li>
    </th:block>
</ul>
```

I want the button to execute a method within the Post class. I'm not sure if I'm using the correct Thymeleaf 'tag'. Right now, when the page loads, it executes the post upvote and downvote methods. 
Can anyone help out? I have a feeling I'm using the wrong Thymeleaf Tag.

Comment: So it seems that I misunderstood the uses of Thymeleaf and that code doesn't exist on the actual page when it's loaded. I don't think there's code that would do this, but a workaround would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a post or get request to invoke those methods. That will only work in JSF, but you can execute the method before de page is rendered as html.

for example this line

```
<p  th:text ="${post.getPostText()}"></p>
```

will be executed before the page is rendered .

What I do here is to hide a form for both action, two buttons with a name attributes and pass some sort of identifier to know witch entity I'm updating. 
In my controller would have two methods that responds to each parameter and return a view or JSON.

Comment: The thing is: I'm not trying to get data for the text or anything. The button is supposed to increment/decrement a variable within the object. I'm going to use something with RequestMapping and will update my question when I get it working.

Answer (score -1):

So they reason I couldn't do what I wanted to do was because Thymeleaf generates HTML as before the pages loads. It doesn't sit in the HTML waiting to be triggered. I ended up changing the HTML to go to a different URL that would be unique to the post.

```
<ul>
    <th:block th:object="${Post}">
        <li class="post" th:each="Post : ${Posts}">
            <p th:text ="${Post.getPostText()}"></p>
            <a th:href = "@{/post?id={id}&vote=1(id=${Post.getPostId()})}">Upvote</a>
            <a th:href = "@{/post?id={id}&vote=0(id=${Post.getPostId()})}">Downvote</a>
            <p th:text = "${Post.getPostVotes()}"></p>
        </li>
    </th:block>
</ul>
```

And this was the corresponding java code in my controller that would update the object:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/post", params = {"id", "vote"})
public String PostVoting(@RequestParam("id") Long id, @RequestParam("vote") int vote)
{
    if (currentUser.voteOnPost(id.toString())){
        return "redirect:/home";
    }
    if(vote == 1){
        int votes = thePostRepository.findById(id).get().getPostVotes() + 1; 
        thePostRepository.updateVotes(votes, id);
    }
    else{
        int votes = thePostRepository.findById(id).get().getPostVotes() - 1; 
        thePostRepository.updateVotes(votes, id);
    }

    return "redirect:/home";
}
```

Also, this next part is important if you want to update things like I did:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Post SET votes = :votes WHERE id = :id")
void updateVotes(@Param("votes") int votes, @Param("id") Long id);
```